# IOS WebView get stuck after some time opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

My webview is getting stuck after 1 hour opened without use it, I'm getting the following errors:

[image]

Someone know what's the problem?

Thank you!

Carles

Comment: Please provide source code of your delegate methods you are using . . . .So that we can check code and give answer

Answer (score 0):

From the Log you can see that is a memory issue "Terminated due to memory issue"
It could be a memory leak or a “zombie” object.

Run the app with instruments to get more info and check if you have forgotten to disable zombies from the scheme editor , Memory Management options